Reset all the settings of an Electron-based app
My Electron app has a menu to Reset All of its settings. I do this by calling fs.rmSync(app.getPath('userData'), { recursive: true }) and it's working fine when it comes to, for instance, the position and size of my app, but... my app allows people to open files (which I do using electron.dialog.showOpenDialog()) and if a user was to resize the open dialog then my Reset All approach will NOT reset the size of the open dialog.
So, how can I reset the size of the open dialog (and other similar dialogs)?
Cheers, Alan.
